# How to refresh a firebase DB token in a loop so it doesn't expire?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, time, firebase-authentication

I tried it via timeloop

```
@tl.job(interval=timedelta(seconds=10))
def sample_job_every_10s():
    print "10s job current time : {}".format(time.ctime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tl.start(block=True)
```

but then I'd have to give the function the variable user in order to do the

```
user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
```

And wasn't able to make it work

Help please!

Thanks!

Comment: Which Python Firebase SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Pyrebase